# How to open a directory in Hammerspoon?

Tags: lua, hammerspoon

I would like to open a directory on Hammerspoon with a keyboard shortcut. In order to open any apps via shortcut, you use the following:

```
hs.hotkey.bind({"ctrl"}, "n", function()
    hs.application.launchOrFocus("Safari")
    end
)
```

However, this doesn't work on the filesystem. For example, if you want to open `~/Dropbox`, what method should you do to open the app?

Comment: By "open a directory", do you mean open the file manager pointing to a particular directory, or open all the files in a particular directory?

Comment: @JackTaylor Open the Finder with the location set to a particular directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is an API specifically suitable for this task, but I found that one solution is bind keys to execute a shell command on Hammerspoon (via `hs.execute()`).

```
local function directoryLaunchKeyRemap(mods, key, dir)
    local mods = mods or {}
    hs.hotkey.bind(mods, key, function()
        local shell_command = "open " .. dir
        hs.execute(shell_command)
    end)
end

directoryLaunchKeyRemap({"ctrl"}, "1", "/Applications")
```

This lets you open `/Applications` directory via <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.